# Event handlers not working in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, event-handling

I have a `TextBox` in my page. That has `INotifyChangeProperty`

All the event handlers (LostFocus, KeyDown, KeyUp) will not fire. Behind the XAML I have C# code.

```
private void TextBox_KeyUp_For_Decimal(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Here is the XAML code

```
<Grid Visibility="{Binding FreeInput, Converter={StaticResource  BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
   <Grid.Resources>
      <TextBox 
         x:Key="StringDefaultPresenter" 
         x:Shared="False" 
         Text="{Binding Default, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" CommandManager.PreviewExecuted="TextBox_PreviewExecuted" 
         LostFocus="Update_Default" 
         KeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown_For_String"/>
      <TextBox 
         x:Key="NumberDefaultPresenter" 
         x:Shared="False" 
         Text="{Binding Default, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"
         CommandManager.PreviewExecuted="TextBox_PreviewExecuted" 
         LostFocus="Update_Default" 
         KeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown_For_Decimal" 
         KeyUp="TextBox_KeyUp_For_Decimal"/>
      <CheckBox 
         x:Key="BooleanDefaultPresenter" 
         x:Shared="False" 
         HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
         VerticalAlignment="Center" 
         LostFocus="Update_Default" 
         IsChecked="{Binding Default, Converter={l:DefaultValueConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>
      <DatePicker 
         x:Key="DateTimeDefaultPresenter" 
         x:Shared="False" 
         SelectedDate="{Binding Default, Converter={l:DefaultValueConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" 
         LostFocus="Update_Default"/>
      <Style x:Key="DefaultPresenterStyle" x:Shared="False" TargetType="ContentControl">
         <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataType}" Value="{x:Static l:DataType.STRING}">
               <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource StringDefaultPresenter}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataType, Converter={l:EnumMatchToBoolConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource NumberDataType}}" Value="True">
               <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource NumberDefaultPresenter}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataType}" Value="{x:Static l:DataType.BOOLEAN}">
               <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource BooleanDefaultPresenter}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataType}" Value="{x:Static l:DataType.DATE_TIME}">
               <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource DateTimeDefaultPresenter}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </Grid.Resources>
   <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource DefaultPresenterStyle}"/>
</Grid>
```

This was working before I added x:Keys to the textboxes and added styles.

Comment: see if your changes did not create a rendering error you can check this by seeing the output window when running the application.

Comment: No rendering error. This is the only error I got. ystem.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'InternalOnly' property not found on 'object' ''SetAttributesPage' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=InternalOnly; DataItem='SetAttributesPage' (Name=''); target element is 'CheckBox' (Name=''); target property is 'IsChecked' (type 'Nullable`1')

Comment: Have you tried handling the `PreviewKeyDown` event instead? Sometimes the `KeyDown` event can be internally consumed by controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. Somehow because of XAML virtualization the handlers are not attached to the events.Setting them explicitly using styles solves the problem.

Like so add this to a TextBox or in this case a ComboBox

```
      <ComboBox
         x:Key="StringLengthPresenter" x:Shared="False"
         SelectedItem="{Binding Length, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
         <ComboBox.Style>
           <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
             <EventSetter Event="SelectionChanged" Handler="Length_SelectionChanged"/>
           </Style>
         </ComboBox.Style>
```